# csv file reads the wrong column

Tags: java, csv

I am trying to read my csv file however inside csv I have to use commas `,` independently from separator.

```
"name1", 'U', Times.perMinute(1, 15), 'A', 1049*2.1,0,          Times.MINUTE*15, False, ['X'] 


"name2", 'U', Times.perHour(1),       'B', 1023*4,  1024*4,      Times.MINUTE*15, True,  ['Y','Z']
```

I try to just read column 4 and 5, but my output seems really weird. I am thinking that problem comes from `,`. How can I solve this?

Edit:

The code that I used

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
         String splitBy = ",";
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("rules.csv"));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] cols = line.split(splitBy);
                System.out.println("Uplink" + cols[4] + " ,Downlink" + cols[5]);
            }
            br.close();
```

Comment: If possible generate csv files with non-ascii separator. In java you could use `char separator=1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**
As stated in my comment,

> You could use a different delimiter, for instance a semicolon, and
> then in your code you'd change the splitBy to a semicolon. That should
> work, but then it's not technically a csv file (comma separated
> values)

because when you simply write Times.perMinute(1, 15) your code parses it as 2 values:

the first being **'Times.perMinute(1'**

and the second **' 15)'**

---

Also please read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180):

> 6. Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
>    should be enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: Your solution is not working as I expected.. even if I changed my csv file as you said

Comment: It's hard for me to say why it's not working as you expect, because I don't know how you're trying to read the "Times.perHour(1)" part and "Times.MINUTE*15". I would guess you're parsing these parts as strings?

Comment: Alright, now the form of the question has changed. You could use a different delimiter, for instance a semicolon, and then in your code you'd change the splitBy to a semicolon. That should work, but then it's not technically a csv file (comma separated values).

Comment: now it is working!! Thanks for help as you said it is not technically csv file but it help me ;)